# Directory not found on `ddev auth ssh`

Tags: ssh, ddev

After entering the command "ddev auth ssh", the message below was displayed.
The ssh key directory "/home/jon/.ssh" was not found.
I have not seen this error before. I'm wondering what I did to cause this.

Comment: Have you checked whether that directory exists on your system (not in the ddev container)?

Comment: If you don't have any keys to add to the ddev ssh agent, then it can't add them. It's expecting them to be in ~/.ssh. However, if you don't have any, you don't need to run `ddev auth ssh` at all. If they're in some other directory for some reason you can use `ddev auth ssh -d /path/to/keys`

Comment: Also, the keys have to be in OpenSSH format.